# Setting the timeout with Knex.js for MSSQL

Tags: node.js, sql-server, knex.js

I use knex.js in a node environment to run a web server that makes sql calls. I have a query that takes over 30 seconds to complete, but when it's run through knex, the default timeout seems to be 15 seconds, so I get the following timeout error:

```
RequestError: Timeout: Request failed to complete in 15000ms
...
```

How do I change the timeout for mssql queries? The official doc has an example of setting timeout on a specific query with `.timeout()` but this feature doesn't work with mssql. I've also tried everything in this [github issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11035) without any luck. After trying all of that, I have this messy looking connection config:

```
const connection = require('knex')({
  client: 'mssql',
  connection: {
    host :  process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' ? '172.18.1.66' : 'localhost',
    user : secrets.user,
    password : secrets.password,
    database : 'EdgeView',
    dialect: "mssql",
    options: {
    'enableArithAbort': true,
    'requestTimeout': 150000,
    'idleTimeoutMillis': 150000
    },
    pool: {
      max: 10,
      min: 0,
      idleTimeoutMillis: 150000
    },
    dialectOptions:{
      requestTimeout: 300000,
      options: {
        "requestTimeout": 300000
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The error did not change, none of these timeout values seems to have had an impact.
The query it's self is just a raw query:

```
let res = connection.raw(GETSQLSTRING(args));
```

Comment: Why don't you use the original mssql module, it has better support for this if you're struggling. https://tediousjs.github.io/node-mssql/

Comment: Thank you, this led me down the right path. So I guess knex is just a wrapper for whatever client type your using? That would explain why there are so many different ways to set the timeout.

Comment: Hate to seem obvious but it just seems easier and there's documentation that exclusively states what you must do for timeout to be extended. :) Hopefully not too much of a back track I deem a few minutes to switch and test.

Comment: I was not aware of this module, all I've had to go on was the knex doc.

Comment: Oh! Just npm check what you want to use, so if it's mysql search npm mysql; you'll get a few module options ones that may solve your issue fastest. Or google around for different modules.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

The answer was simply this:

```
const connection = require('knex')({
  client: 'mssql',
  connection: {
    host :  'edge-sql',
    user : secrets.user,
    password : secrets.password,
    requestTimeout: 600000,
    database : 'EdgeView'
  }
});
```

Thanks to BGPHiJACK for pointing me towards better documentation.